# jQuery draggable leaving cloned html behind

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am using jQuery UI; Draggable http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable invoked like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#side_bar").sortable({
        revert: true
    });

    $(".draggable").draggable({ 
                              containment: 'parent', 
                              hascroll: true, 
                              handle: 'div.box_header',
                              scrollSensitivity: 100,
                              scrollSpeed: 100, 
                              axis: 'y',                                 
                              connectToSortable: '#side_bar',                                 
                              helper: 'clone',
                              opacity: 0.35 
                              }); });
```

You can see the html structure on http://www.sarsclan.co.uk (right side bar area).

It seems to create a transparant clone as your dragging, but when you drop it puts the draggable div in the right place, but leaves the original div in it's place and just appends the dom with a clone of that original div in its new place.

Comment: This is now SOLVED, thank you for responces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demos on jqueryui Sortable show no extra `draggable` call, as far as I can see: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/. Have you tried to do with a `sortable` call only?

EDIT: I can see that your code is similar to the "Draggable + Sortable" example on the jqueryui site. However, that example always clones the element at the top and inserts the clone into the sortable list, so that's not what you want to achieve.

Comment: You are right! I didn't need draggable at all! I just used the one sortable call and it is doing everything I was trying to achieve with draggable, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Do you really mean to have " helper: ' clone' " ? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: If I remove help: clone then the user gets no visual feedback as they drag. Plus it seems to make div jump all over all the place while dragging